Does evaluating a slot of a map from the product topology, result in a new continous function from component of product?
Suppose, we have that $f: X \times Y -> Z$ is a continous function with $X \times Y$ having the product topology inherited from $X$ and $Y$. Take some $a \in Y$, is it true that $ \color{orange}{f(x,a)= \tilde{f}: X \to Z}$ is continous?
I believe the answer is yes.
Proof attempt:
We are given that
$$f^{-1}(U_z) =  \cap \cup U_x \times U_y$$
Where the choice of symbol $U$ is to denote openness.
We must now prove that $$\tilde{f}^{-1} (U_z)= U_x$$
I believe that this should lead to something like
$$ \color{red}{ \text{preim}_{ \tilde{f}(x,a) } (U_z) = \cap \cup U_x \times (U_y\cap \{b\})} = U_x$$
But I am not sure how to justify this..
Note: Cups and caps are meant to denote the open set are a union and finite of intersection of basis elements.

You cannot write $f^{-1}(U_z) = U_x \times U_y$ - while sets of the form $U_x \times U_y$ are open, they only form a basis for the product topology - in general an open set is a union of such sets.

Consider the continuous functions $id_X:X\to X$ and $c_a:X\to Y$, $c_a(x)=a$. Then $i_a:X\to X\times Y$, $i_a(x)=(x,a)$ is a function such that $\pi_X\circ i_a=id_X$ and $\pi_Y\circ i_a=c_a$. By the universal property of product, $i_a$ is continuous. Finally, $\widetilde f=f\circ i_a$.

I don't think we should assume knowledge of the universal property, so perhaps I would show $i_a$ is continuous directly from the definition. But that is how I would approach it.

What have you tried?

To say the same thing as others but in different language, you are essentially just restricting $f$ to a subspace ($X\times{a}$) and a restriction of continuous functions is always continuous

@FShrike Well, you are babalobally just restricting $f$ to the subspace $X\times {a}$, where the babalobal restriction of $f$ to $G$ is the composition of $f$ with an embedding $i:X\to X\times Y$ such that $i(X)=G$. The babalobal restriction of a continuous function is continuous.

@SassatelliGiulio is this an attempt at saying it again in yet another ‘language’? Babalobal gives me Jabberwocky vibes

No, it's a remark about you using the buzzword "essentially" to mask a topological detail, instead of stating it explicitly.

@SassatelliGiulio Uh, the only thing "essentially" masks is the very unimportant detail that $X$ and $X\times{a}$ are homeomorphic.
